# Adding HTML/Text to Top of Subscriber's Profile Backend Page

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles, profiles

After a new user creates an account and logs in, the subscriber lands at the `/wp-admin/profile.php` page. With certain demographics, I've found some users tend to get stuck there.

I'd like to be able to add HTML such as a descriptive paragraph with links to areas on the site, to the top of the Subscriber level Profile page; if possible between the 'Profile' header and 'Personal Details'.

Uses for this include directing users back to applications, specific forms, etc.

Pseudo code for envisioned `profile.php` is:

```
...
<h1>Profile</h1>
```

if user is subscriber, then echo:

```
<div class="subscriberProfile">
    <p>Looking for the <a href="http://example.com/form">Example Form</a>?</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just redirect after login, to a different page altogether?  Personally I don't like dropping the user into their profile page...would rather have a nicer page to land on.

Comment: That's definitely plausible for sites where users have only one segment of subscribers; i.e. users only register for x, etc., but if users are registering for a-z, the landing page could become less effective. I could definitely see myself using that for a registration exclusive to applications, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code to your `functions.php` to add a notice for users with the `subscriber` role on their profile and dashboard admin pages.

```
function wpse239290_user_welcome_notice() {
    // Make sure that the user is assigned to the subscriber role, specifically.
    // Alternatively, capabilities can be checked with current_user_can(), but roles are not supposed to be checked this way.
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ! in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Make sure the profile or dashboard screens are being viewed.
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( ! $screen || ( 'profile' !== $screen->id && 'dashboard' !== $screen->id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Show a friendly green notice, and allow it to be dismissed (it will re-appear if the page is reloaded though).
    $class = 'notice notice-success is-dismissible';

    // Customize the HTML to  fit your preferences.
    $message = '<p>Looking for the <a href="http://example.com/form">Example Form</a></p>';

    printf( '<div class="%1$s"><div class="subscriberProfile">%2$s</div></div>', $class, $message ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse239290_user_welcome_notice' );
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot in the dev environment. I'm assuming this goes on functions.php rather than the profile.php template? I'll find out soon enough.

Comment: How could I make this apply to the dashboard too? `if ( ! $screen || 'profile' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }` something about OR 'dashboard'

Comment: Sure! Updated the code so that it works on the dashboard too.

Comment: Thanks Dave. This has been really helpful. PS: Dave Romsey ~ Ramsey, that's priceless. Thanks for formatting the post. That is helpful to know too.